# Getting the node.js monitor-dashboard project to work externally

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the `monitor-dashboard` project to work but i get a page can't be found error when I try to use a browser externally.
http://lorenwest.github.io/monitor-dashboard/

Internally seems OK, I'm getting a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` from `http://localhost:4200` with the usual curl command.

I went in to `node/node_modules/monitor-dashboard/config/`, and changed `default.js` and `external.js` and changed all occurrences of `allowExternalConnections` to `true`.

I've also got `node-monitor` loaded in to my node project.

I'm running `node server.js` first and then `npm start monitor-dashboard` in another window.

port 4200 is open via `iptables -L`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The setting you're looking for is:

export NODE_ENV=external